# Android scoped storage with getExternalFilesDir - How can I set default directory to a more user friendly one?

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I am developing an android app using Python and Kivy, currently I want to set up File Browser/Picker in the way that Android 11 and API 30 will be cooperating properly (I mean this "new" scoped storage).

I think I managed to do this with this code:

```
Env = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
_activity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity").mActivity
_external_storage_path = _activity.getExternalFilesDir(Env.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath()
data_dir = _external_storage_path
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)
```

I was hoping that `Env.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` will let me guide user directly to his "documents" folder but instead it's just creating this folder deep into file tree.

Currently after opening file picker is showing this directory - `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.myapp/files/Documents/` and instead I would like it to show user - `/storage/emulated/0/` since there he can view his files.

Is it possible to do while cooperating with new requirements for storage in Android 11 / API 30 ?

Comment: Of course. In the usual way. As before Android 11.

Comment: `but instead it's just creating this folder deep into file tree.` Of course as you use it as folder parameter for getExternalFilesDir.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you, but could you please elaborate a little bit more about this "usual way" ? I read that it could be done with `getExternalStorageDirectory()` but this one is being deprecated as far as I have read?

Comment: Deprecated indeed. But working. Use it. But better getExternalStoragePublicDirectory indicating your public folder.

Comment: @blackapps But doesn't `deprecated` mean that my app will stop working in some time as google will decide that it is time to stop supporting deprecated features?

Comment: Yes, but then you will be warned long before so you can adapt your code then. Android 15?

Comment: @blackapps Ah, I understand. Thank you. I was thinking that this code is a part of features that google will turn off mid Android 11, but I guess I confused it with other things. Thank you!

Comment: You won't be able to put new APKs on the play store using this method from sometime in August, but you can keep doing it if not using the play store.

Comment: @inclement I just uploaded it and it went fine, I didn't receive warning. I think I would receive warning about August if I have used API below 30. Isn't that what you mean?

Comment: I don't know if you would receive a warning, the important thing is that regardless of that you can read google's publicly available announcements to see that you must target api 30+ from August.